# How to grant run time permission for Android API 23?

Tags: android, permissions

Experts,

Below is my code,

problem description: error happen at db.execSQL statement says null db object.

I tried to check what is wrong, and applied 2 toast, find out "test" not show, my understanding it means checkSelfPermission judgement is false, so I have the permission already. But if I write db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase() directly, it would have "unknown error (code 14): Could not open database".

I really have no clue, please help, thanks in advance.

```
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

Code:

```
public class AbcActivity extends Activity {

SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 111222:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(Global.dataFolder + File.separator + "xxxxx", null);
            else {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_param);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    111222);
        else
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    111222);
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(Global.dataFolder + File.separator + "xxxxx", null);
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists " + "xxxxx" + "(" +
            //<editor-fold desc="columns">
            "DtdKink REAL," +
            "TttBin REAL" +
            //</editor-fold>
            ")");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think It's not related with permissions, you should use `SQLiteOpenHelper` class to use SQLite.

Example:

```
public class FeedReaderDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FeedReader.db";

    public FeedReaderDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
    }
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
        // to simply to discard the data and start over
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }
}
```

Info from:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

EDIT:

In API 23 openOrCreateDatabase() not create the folder when you are trying to create it in the external storage, try to do it before calling this method

Check this solution:

```
File root = new File(Global.dataFolder + File.separator);
if (!root.exists()) {
    //Create folder
    root.mkdirs();
}
db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(Global.dataFolder + File.separator + "xxxxx", null);
                db.execSQL("create table if not exists " + "xxxxx" + "(" +
                //<editor-fold desc="columns">
                "DtdKink REAL," +
                "TttBin REAL" +
                //</editor-fold>
                ")");
```

Comment: could you explain what is wrong with db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase statement please? It runs success on API 21. PS. I start to worry, since you replied, people would though it answered and I would wait no right answer. I

Comment: openOrCreateDatabase(name, mode, factory) method is in Context class, so you should use your base activity SQLiteDatabase db = getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase("DATABASE",android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE ,null);

Comment: Sorry I don't follow. As I mentioned, the code works on API 21. It seems you are saying I should modify the db statement, but toast "test" not execute, means no chance to execute "db=SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase". This is first a logic problem.

Comment: I cancel all the permission related statements, and run //db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(). Then it works on API 21, fail on API 23. So I believe it is not syntax problem, but permission problem.

Comment: That's why I add permission, but now toast "test" result suggests I already have the permission, that's where I was confused and lost the clue.

Comment: Please ask me question if I was not provide clear description, not need to answer rashly.

Comment: Actually the code I provided is almost complete, if somebody run it on both API 21 and 23, ...

Comment: Let's go by little steps: Talking only about Request Permissions at run time, this is an asynchronous process so  db.execSQL is going to run before user granted permissions in API 23

Comment: Check only permissions at run time in versions above API 23: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){ checkPermissions()}

Comment: You could use SQLiteDatabase db = getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase("DATABASE",android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVA‌​TE ,null); to stored by default in a subfolder of your app folder in the internal storage, so you don't need any permission

Comment: This time I fully understand, but still don't know how to solve my problem. 1. I need to create the db in external storage. 2. I need the permission and it must be synchronous, the remaining codes depends on the db.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118425/discussion-between-miguel-benitez-and-caibirdcnb).